# How Install Beamer Themes in OS X?

Tags: latex

Themes are [here](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html).
I do the following and notice that noting change in my presentation

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{CambridgeUS}
```

How can you install Beamer themes in OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard "complete" themes like CambridgeUS and others, which are listed in the [beameruserguide](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beameruserguide), should have been installed together with the `beamer` package and can be use as described in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beameruserguide):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
```

`outer themes` are just a subset of the whole `beamer` theming approach (e.g. `infolines`).

With regard to installing other custom themes: simply put them into a sub-folder of your local `texmf` tree under `~/Library/texmf/`.

Comment: I had much problems with my PATH when using Macports and Homebrew together. I noticed that this problem also was solved by uninstalling Macports completely.